# How to create a style of arc in gradient color with text value in the middle in WPF to be used for button, Label and Textblock

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpf-controls, wpf-style

Here is the desired effect:

[image: Arc with value in the middle]

Is it possible to create such style in WPF so that it can be used for button, label and textblock as static resource?

Thank you

Comment: what did you try so far?

Comment: As @DenisSchaf says, it'd be easier to help if you post what you tried so far, and what is not working or what you are struggling with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a sample of a `UserControl` that have the similar look of your image. This doesn't work on every case you mentioned but I hope this puts you on a good direction.

**AwesomArcControl.xaml**

```xml
<UserControl
    x:Class="GradientBrushSample.AwesomArcControl"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:local="using:GradientBrushSample"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid>
        <Viewbox>
            <Path>
                <Path.Stroke>
                    <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0.5,0" EndPoint="0.5,1">
                        <GradientStop Offset="0.0" Color="Yellow" />
                        <GradientStop Offset="0.25" Color="Red" />
                        <GradientStop Offset="0.75" Color="Blue" />
                        <GradientStop Offset="1.0" Color="LimeGreen" />
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                </Path.Stroke>
                <Path.Data>
                    <PathGeometry>
                        <PathGeometry.Figures>
                            <PathFigureCollection>
                                <PathFigure StartPoint="25,50">
                                    <PathFigure.Segments>
                                        <PathSegmentCollection>
                                            <ArcSegment
                                                IsLargeArc="True"
                                                Point="50,25"
                                                Size="25,25"
                                                SweepDirection="Clockwise" />
                                        </PathSegmentCollection>
                                    </PathFigure.Segments>
                                </PathFigure>
                            </PathFigureCollection>
                        </PathGeometry.Figures>
                    </PathGeometry>
                </Path.Data>
            </Path>
        </Viewbox>
        <Viewbox>
            <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Content, Mode=OneWay}" />
        </Viewbox>
    </Grid>

</UserControl>
```

**AwesomArcControl.xaml.cs**

```cs
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml;
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls;

namespace GradientBrushSample;

public sealed partial class AwesomArcControl : UserControl
{
    public AwesomArcControl()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    // The "new" keyword hides the UserControl's base member "Content".
    public new object Content
    {
        get => (object)GetValue(ContentProperty);
        set => SetValue(ContentProperty, value);
    }

    // The "new" keyword hides the UserControl's base member "ContentProperty".
    public static new readonly DependencyProperty ContentProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        nameof(Content),
        typeof(object),
        typeof(AwesomArcControl),
        new PropertyMetadata(default));
}
```

And you can use it like this:

```xml
<Button
    x:Name="AwesomeButton"
    Width="50"
    Height="50"
    Padding="0">
    <local:AwesomArcControl Content="9" />
</Button>
```

- [LinearGradientBrush](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.media.lineargradientbrush?view=winrt-22621)
- [Path for arcs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/graphics-multimedia/how-to-create-an-elliptical-arc?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8)
- [new keyword as modifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/new-modifier)

Comment: great answer, high effort

Comment: That's brilliant! I am wondering if I have really leaned WPF. Fantastic!